# ASP.NET MVC Razor－DropDownList Width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, styles, width, html.dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainAD, DepartmentList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:80px" } })
```

Why 【@style = "width:80px"】 no effect ?

How can I change width of html.DropDownListFor ?

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('select').addClass("form-control");
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please upload images [directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to your post. Images uploaded to third party servies might be deleted in future.

Comment: Try; `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainAD, DepartmentList, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:80px" })` doesn't need `htmlAttributes = new`

Comment: Thank you for giving me good advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DepartmentList is a type of select list slight change in code is required, instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainAD, DepartmentList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:80px" } })
```

use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainAD, DepartmentList,htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:80px" })
```

htmlAttributes is the parameter of DropDownListFor, not a property of the parameter